# phpinfo() shows imagemagick 7 but cli says imagemagick 6

Tags: laravel, imagemagick, valet

using valet on mac. everything is working in valet for my laravel site, but i notice a slight pdf positioning difference after deploying the site via laravel forge. Server is Digital Ocean ubuntu 22.04, php 8.2, imagemagick 7. I'm thinking the cli version on the mac is the problem but i can't switch versions so that the cli is also version 7. Everything is also working on the deployed site except for the slight position problem. Anyone have any suggestions for me?

installed latest imagemagick via homebrew, pecl, etc. I was expecting cli to update cli to imagemagick 7. I restarted brew services and valet.

Comment: The version you have installed on your computer has nothing to do with the version that the PHP module was compiled with.